# Mersenne Prime Sequences

Tags: prime-numbers, nt.number-theory

Hi.

Given the following sequence (of Mersenne primes):

$ A_{1} = 2 $

$ A_{n} = 2^{A_{n-1}} - 1 $

The first five elements are all prime numbers:

$ 2 $

$ 2^{2}-1=3 $

$ 2^{3}-1=7 $

$ 2^{7}-1=127 $

$ 2^{127}-1=170141183460469231731687303715884105727 $

As far as my memory serves, it has been conjectured that this sequence contains ONLY prime numbers.

Sadly, calculating the sixth element (let alone proving it's a prime number or providing a counterexample) appears computationally infeasible, so I guess that this remains an open conjecture.

My question is with regards to a similar type of sequences:

$ B_{n} = 2^{B_{n-1}} - 1 $

Where $ B_{1} $ is a Mersenne prime which is NOT in $ A_{n} $

Has it been conjectured that ANY such sequence will ALWAYS contain a composite number?

Thanks

Comment: The Wagstaff heuristics http://primes.utm.edu/mersenne/heuristic.html assert that for large prime $p$, the probability of $2^p-1$ being prime is about $(\log p)/p$ (up to some multiplicative constant). So it seems unlike to me that $A_n$ contains only prime numbers. I would rather conjecture that any such sequence will contain a composite number.

Comment: Yes, for a discussion see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Mersenne_number. Whether Catalan really conjectured that all of $A_n$ are prime is not clear to me.

Comment: Thank you Francois!
$2^{p}-1$ is a Mersenne number.
I think that the probability of a Mersenne number to be in $A{n}$ is smaller than the probability of a Mersenne number to be a prime.
So if I'm correct, then your probabilistic argument cannot be used in order to conclude that it is unlikely for $A{n}$ to contain only prime numbers.


Comment: Based on the heuristics mentioned by Francois, it seems rather reasonable to conjecture that $A_n$ is composite for all $n \geq 6$.



Comment: @Barakman : The point is that there is no obvious bias towards primality arising from belonging to $A_n$. The exponents of the numbers in $A_n$ are very large, and I see no reason why they should be more prime than the Mersenne numbers of comparable size. So their primality becomes soon unlikely.

Comment: @Dietrich : Eugène Catalan's footnote is here http://archive.org/stream/nouvellecorresp01mansgoog#page/n353/mode/2up

In fact, he states this as an "empirical theorem" which holds for all terms "up to a certain limit". To me this seems far from conjecturing that all terms are prime.

Comment: @François: I agree. Thank you for the interesting link (I am still reading...).

Comment: On the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Mersenne_number, it says that M(M(13)), M(M(17), M(M(19)), and M(M(31))=M(M(M(5))) are all composite, and factors have been found. The next possibility for your B1 is 61.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault : Mersenne-numbers and iterated Mersenne-numbers of the same size have the significant difference, that the iterated ones cannot have "small" prime-factors while for the basic Mersenne numbers there is no such restriction. For instance a two-time iterated Mersenne number cannot have primefactors $3,5,11, ... $ and only $7,23,..$ can be primefactors of such a number. So the possible number-of-primefactors for highly iterated Mersenne-numbers is much smaller than a naive expectation.

Comment: This looks even more drastical for higher iterates. Let's denote $n_0$ a  variable having any positive integer value, $n_1 = 2^{n_0}-1$, $n_2 = 2^{n_1}-1$ and so on. Then $n_4$ can have at most two primefactors below $10,000$, namely $2879$ and $4703$ or at most $5$ primefactors below $100,000$  and the likeliness of being prime, based on subsequent statistical considerations only, should be much larger that that of a non-iterated Mersennenumber of the same size.

Answer (score 2):

*Remark: I'm composing my two comments at the OP making them an answer*

Mersenne-numbers and iterated Mersenne-numbers of the same size have the significant difference, that the iterated ones cannot have "small" prime-factors while for the basic Mersenne numbers there is no such restriction. For instance a two-time iterated Mersenne number cannot have primefactors $3,5,11,...$ and only $7,23,..$ can be primefactors of such a number. So the possible number-of-primefactors for highly iterated Mersenne-numbers is much smaller than a naive expectation based on that for non-iterated Mersenne-numbers of the same size.

This looks even more drastical for higher iterates. Let's denote $n_0$ a variable having any positive integer value, $n_1=2^{n_0}−1,$, $n_2=2^{n_1}−1$ and so on. Then any $n_4$ can have at most two of the primes below $10,000$ as factors, namely $2879$ and $4703$ (or: at most $5$ of the primes below $100,000$ can be factors, or at most $21$ of the primes below $1,000,000$) and the likelihood of being prime for some $n_4$, based on the required subsequent statistical considerations only, should be much larger than that of a non-iterated Mersennenumber $n_1$ of the same size.

---

*Appended: for any $n_5$ we have only $3$ primes below $1,000,000$ as possible primefactors, namely $214559$,$429119$ and $858239$*

Answer (score 0):

Iterated sequences have finite number of primes, it have been proved for elliptic sequence, and polynomial maps, see the works of Graham and company on elliptic curve, and a student of Silverman wrote a thesis on this, it is on the arxiv.

Comment: Welcome to MO! Could you perhaps provide some more details. (You can expand the answer via clicking 'edit' just below it.)

Comment: Euclid proved the opposite, for a certain iterated sequence, and thus for infinitely many other iterated sequences.  Later Dirichlet improved upon this by showing it held for every possible permissible instance of the iterated sequence. Gerhard "Is Talking About Iterated Adding" Paseman, 2013.06.17

Comment: I think that alias is overstating what's been proven. There are *certain* elliptic divisibility sequences and *certain* polynomial orbits for which one can prove there are only finitely many primes. Some of these, in particular the ones that Graham Everest and his colleagues/students studied, can be somewhat subtle to prove; but roughly speaking, they all come from cases where there is a "map" from some other sequence that provides a nontrivial divisor. Of course, there are also trivial examples. But in general, it is only *conjectured* that EDS and poly orbits have finitely many primes.

Comment: @JoeSilverman : but here it is an exponential iterated sequence, is there any reason to think that $\displaystyle 2^{\textstyle  2^{127}-1}-1$ is not prime and that there are not an infinity of primes when continuing the sequence ?

Comment: @user1952009 Let $a_n$ be a sequence of positive integers whose entries don't have any particular reason to be composite, for example the sequence you suggest $2^{2^n}-1$. The "probability" that $a_n$ is prime is roughly $1/\log a_n$, so a rough heuristic is that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\log a_n}$ converges, then the sequence contains finitely many primes, and if it diverges, then the sequence contains infinitely many primes. N.B. This is just a very coarse heuristic, it generally needs to be refined to take account of congruence conditions. But since you ask for a reason, there is it.

Comment: @JoeSilverman : yes I know that, but it is independent of the fact that $2^{2}-1$,$2^{2^2-1}-1$,$2^{2^{2^2-1}-1}-1,2^{2^{2^{2^2-1}-1}-1}-1$ are all primes (even if only the two last really matter). the only fact I know is that $2^{2^{31}-1}-1$ has been shown composite, but it is a different double Mersenne iterated sequence. but if you look on [wiki/Double_Mersenne_number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Mersenne_number#Double_Mersenne_primes) you'll think that the empirical probability that $2^{2^p-1}-1$ is prime when $2^p-1$ is prime is quite.... high.